# Define variables

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

Is it ok to define a variable like this:

```
var myVariableName = (var1 > 0) ? "yay" : "nay";
```

or is it best to wrap the varaible in the if statment:

```
if(var1 > 0){
  var myVariableName = "yay";
}else{
  var myVariableName = "nay";
}
```

Comment: Why do you think the conditional operator would be a bad idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with

```
var myVariableName = (var1 > 0) ? "yay" : "nay";
```

It's easier to read. Note the parentheses aren't necessary.

Another way to write it would be like this, taking advantage of the way the boolean operators behave:

```
var myVariableName = var1 > 0 && "yay" || "nay";
```